# Elasticsearch: Incorrect score

Tags: elasticsearch

The behavior of searching for several words is not quite clear. I'm running the following query:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": {
                    "multi_match": {
                        "query":"Testcat y",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "fields": fields
                    }
                },
            }
        }
```

But search results looks strange for me:

```
{
        "score": 7.925287,
        "text": "Yappies",
    },
    {
        "score": 7.925287,
        "text": "YourPetBuddy",
    },
    {
        "score": 7.925287,
        "text": "YourDog",
    },

    {
        "score": 6.270683,
        "text": "Testcat",
    },
```

I use the following settings:

```
BASE_SETTINGS = {
    'settings': {
        "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 0,
        'analysis': {

            'filter': {
                'autocomplete_filter': {
                    'type': 'edge_ngram',
                    'min_gram': 1,
                    'max_gram': 16
                }
            },

            'analyzer': {
                'autocomplete': {
                    'type': 'custom',
                    'tokenizer': "standard",
                    'filter': [
                        'lowercase',
                        'autocomplete_filter'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the Testcat not supposed to be with a higher score? Because it has a greater match with the search string

Upd: For searching i'm already use standard search analyzer

```
'properties': {
                        field['name']: {
                            'type': 'text',
                            'analyzer': 'autocomplete',
                            'search_analyzer': 'standard'
                        } for field in MAPPING_FIELDS[index]['fields']
                    }
```

How can I assign the highest score to the largest prefix?

Comment: try running the search query with ?explain=true parameter. You will get a detailed breakdown of the scoring going on.
`GET index/_search?explain=true`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your indexing process and search query use the same analyzer. With indexing it creates 16 grams for that field for each document:

```
Testcat: t te tes ...
Yappies: y ya yap...
```

If you do not use a different analyzer during search, the same thing happens to your query for each token (split on space because of standard tokenizer):

```
Testcat: t te tes ...
y: y
```

Because of the elaborate amount of tokens, a lot of your documents get hit bu I'm guessing here that `y` is a *more unique* token in your index for that field in that index and because of that, those documents are more relevant.

Try using a different analyzer during search that does not include the `edge_ngram` filter, as described here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html

Comment: Same thing applies: in your search `y` is a token, in your documents `y` is also a token (because of `edge_ngram`) and `y` is pretty unique in your index. If you would search for `testcast yyy` your results would probably be more what you expect.